# can we create multiple pure virtual interfaces in hierarchy and their implementation without code explosion

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, pure-virtual

In implementations of pure virtual classe (B_Impl below) do we need to define all methods corresponding to all derived pure virtual classes (A and B) even if we are also deriving from implementation classes (A_Impl). 
I have following pure virtual classes:

```
class A
{
public:
virtual bool M1() = 0;
virtual ~A() = default;
};

class A_Impl: public virtual A
{
public:
bool M1() override { return true;}
virtual ~A_Impl() = default;
};

class B : public virtual A
{
public:
virtual ~B()=default;
virtual bool M2() = 0;
};

class B_Impl : public B, public A_Impl
{
public:
virtual ~B_Impl() = default;
bool M2() override { return true; }
};

int main()
{
    B_Impl bimpl();
    return 0;
}
```

On compiling this I am getting following error:

1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
1.cpp:31:5: error: invalid abstract return type ‘B_Impl’
     B_Impl bimpl();
     ^~~~~~
1.cpp:22:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘B_Impl’:
 class B_Impl : public B, public A_Impl
       ^~~~~~
1.cpp:4:14: note:   virtual bool A::M1()
 virtual bool M1() = 0;

I dont want to define all methods of A in B_Impl as well when I am deriving from A_Impl also.

Comment: Your code have more problems than that, e.g. `error: 'virtual bool B::M2()' cannot be defaulted`

Comment: Can you please provide a fully working code (expect your problem)

Comment: Edited the code to be in working condition and give proper error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code lacks of multiple problems.

First `A_Impl` does not derive from `A`, which means, that it cannot override `M1`.

I think your approach is not elaborate very well and you should consider rethink your architecture.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem here is that a `B_Impl` object has two `A` subobjects, one of which does not have its `M1` method overridden.

A `B_Impl` object looks something like this:

```
+-------------------------+
| +---------+ +---------+ |
| | +-----+ | | +-----+ | |
| | |     | | | |     | | |
| | |  A  | | | |  A  | | |
| | |     | | | |     | | |
| | +-----+ | | +-----+ | |
| |  A_Impl | |  B      | |
| +---------+ +---------+ |
|         B_Impl          |
+-------------------------+
```

It has `A_Impl` and `B` subojtects, each of which has its own `A` subobject.

To fix this, you need to use virtual inheritance.  If you declare `A_Impl` and `B` to inherit virtually from `A`, then `B_Impl` will end up looking like this:

```
+--------------------------+
| +-----+ +------+ +-----+ |
| |     | |      | |     | |
| |  A  | |A_Impl| |  B  | |
| |     | |      | |     | |
| +-----+ +------+ +-----+ |
|          B_Impl          |
+--------------------------+
```

It has one `A` subojbect that is shared by `B` and `A_Impl`.

To do that, just add the `virtual` keyword:

```
class A                               
{                                        
public:
    virtual bool M1() = 0;
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

class A_Impl : public virtual A
{
public:
    bool M1() override { return true;}
    virtual ~A_Impl() = default;
};

class B : public virtual A
{
public:
    virtual bool M2() = 0;
    virtual ~B()=default;
};

class B_Impl : public virtual B, public A_Impl
{
public:
    virtual ~B_Impl() = default;
    bool M2() override { return true; }
};
```

Note that I've also declared `B_Impl` to derive virtually from `B`.  In general, it's a good idea to inherit virtually from interfaces.  That way you won't end up with the same problem if you mix in a `C` interface that derives from `B` and a `C_Impl` that derives from `C` and `B_Impl`.

Just keep in mind that it's the most-derived class's job to initialize any virtually-derived-from classes, so if you were to make `A` non-default-constructable then it would end up being the responsibility of `B_Impl` to call `A`'s constructor rather than that responsibility being hidden by `A_Impl`.

Comment: Thanks :) this worked for me but I don't want to introduce virtual inheritance.